# Vite + Laravel + Inertia - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on npm run dev

Tags: laravel, vite, inertiajs, laravel-10

I started having an issue starting from today when running `npm run dev` when running `php artisan serve --host=IP` using vite + laravel (i'm using breeze boilerplate as a starter).

Basically, it was working just fine for over a month until today, i started having the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED [::1]:5173.

I tried changing the server in `vite.config.js` as follows:

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        port: 5173,
        hmr: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
        },
    },
...
```

The only ways i can make it work is either by running `npm run build` or by manually putting the server on the vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: "192.168.31.166",
        port: 5173,
        hmr: {
            host: "192.168.31.166",
        },
    },
...
```

I do not want to have to change the server manually every time, as i don't have a fixed IP Address and use 2 different wifi configurations based on if I'm at work or working remotely.
Did anyone face those issues? I tried running `npm update` and `composer update` so i'm on latest versions for Laravel (10.8.0) and Vite (4.3.1), it didn't fix it.

Thank you in advance!

> **TL;DR:**
> Tried running `npm run dev` and `php artisan serve --host=IP` and got an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead of the normal behaviour (was working just fine before)

Comment: I might skipped some details regarding my setup:
- Running this on a Macbook Pro M2, macOS Ventura v13.3.1
- Firewall is disabled just in case
- Running on node 18.12.1
- I did update all homebrew packages as well (mysql 5.7, nginx, dnsmasq, php, tried also with Laravel Valet and got the same problem.)

Comment: anyone found solution?

Comment: @MarsadAkbar Sorry mate, I have no idea how it started working back again one day. I believe it was a vite update that fixed it. You can try going to 4.4.6 or higher if you're not already using one of those.

Comment: Thanks to your question I was able to get the auto reload to work by manually setting the server config for vite